# Spring security redirects behind reverse proxy in kubernetes

Tags: java, spring, nginx, spring-security, kubernetes

I have Spring Security application deployed in kubernetes without servlet context path.
In ingress (nginx reverse proxy) I have rewrite rule:

for example /api/oauth-server/authorize -> /authorize

so my login page should be accessed via www.example.com/api/oauth-server/login from outside, but Spring Security redirects me to www.example.com/login. It is because my login page is on /login in application. I want Spring Security redirect me to www.example.com/api/oauth-server/login

How to solve this redirect issue behind the reverse proxy to make it work? This should be common issue, but I did not find any resource with practical info.

Comment: You can check when the redirect takes place by using `curl -v -L www.example.com/api/oauth-server/login 2>&1 | egrep "^> (Host:|GET)"`

Comment: Did you find a solution? We encounter the same issue, and can't manage it so far...

Comment: I did not solve this, I stopped using url rewrites so I have to set servlet context path in each application.